# Unlock HR user in Oracle 12C

Tags: oracle, database-connection, oracle12c

I'm trying to unlock HR user; I've tried all the possible way, but I'm not able to achieve it.

Below are the steps I've followed in the attempt to achieve that:

**Step 1**: Updated my `tnsname.ora` file

```
PDBORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl)
    )
  )
```

**Step 2**: Switch the container from `CBD$ROOT` to `PDBORCL`

**Step 3**: `ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = pdborcl;`

**Step 4**: `ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE open;`

**Step 5**: `ALTER USER hr IDENTIFIED BY hr ACCOUNT unlock;`

**Step 6**: `conn hr/hr @pdborcl;`

Up to step 5, I get everything working well as expected, but on step 6, I get this error:

> ORA-01045: hr user lacks create session privileges; logon denied

I try to grant privileges by logging as below:

```
connect sys/password as sysdba;

grant create session to hr
```

The result: `grant succeeded`.

Now again when I try to connect to hr schema running

```
conn hr/hr @pdborcl;
```

I get the same previous error again.

What can account for this?

When I set **`SID = pdborcl`** from SQL Developer, I get this error:

> ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve these errors?

Comment: You have to use the service name to connect from SQL Developer too, not the SID - pick the other option in the connection dialog. But you'll have the same ORA problem until you fix the error from SQL\*Plus, so that's a side issue....

Comment: I have connected now using service name i.e. pdborcl, it's connected. But Why is that, I'm not able to see HR tables after connecting. Did I miss any step?

Answer (score 1):

once you connect using sysdba you need to set the session to pdb and then grant HR user create session access.

conn / as sysdba
alter session set container=pdborcl;
grant create session to HR;
exit
sqlplus hr/hr@pdborcl
connected.

Comment: Why is that, I'm not able to see HR tables  after connecting,
Here: sqlplus hr/hr@pdborcl

Comment: if HR does not contain any tables, then you will not be able to see any tables owned by HR.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more entry in tnsnames.ora file for pdb.

```
PDBORCL1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl1)
    )
  )
```